# Laravel-5 redirecting to /home after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm building a custom authentication system with roles in Laravel-5.1.

I have two sets of users, supervisors and administrators.  But I only have one login page.  So when the user logs in, it authenticates their credentials first, then I have written a middleware which checks which kind of user they are.

If they are an administrator, it should redirect them to `/admin/home`.  If they are a supervisor it should redirect them to `supervisor/home`.

I can see from the source file `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php` that the default redirect is to `/home`.  However, how can I change that so it becomes dynamic?

**My routes file:**

```
/* Administrator Routes */

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'timesheets.admin:1'], function()
{
    return Route::get('admin/home', 'AdminController@index');
});

/* Supervisor Routes */

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Supervisor', 'middleware' => 'timesheets.supervisor:2'], function()
{
    return Route::get('supervisor/home', 'SupervisorController@index');
});
```

**My middleware file:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\Auth;

use Closure, App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class AdminAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        /* Get user id */
        $userId = $this->auth->user()->userId();

        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole($userId, $role)) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            App::abort(403);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, set the `$redirectPath` in your AuthController like:

```
$redirectPath = 'Path/to/standard/user/on/authentication'
```

Create a new middleware called Admin that would look like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
    {
        return redirect('path/to/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

You will need to create a new method within your user Model to check for admin.

Like so:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->admin;
}
```

This would return the value of your admin field in your users table.

Then on your `SupervisorController` `__construct()` you could call your admin middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('admin');

}
```

This will make the admin land at the standard login, but redirect them to the admin home almost immediately.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  The redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: Have you added `'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,` in Kernel.php?

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Apologies, I have updated the admin middleware method. Try that please.

Comment: Thanks but now it looks like it's doing an infinite redirect loop `The page isn't redirecting properly`

Comment: Should I remove the middleware on my admin route now?

Comment: Sorry, I left out an important step. Your auth controller is using guest middleware. In authController comment out `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85025/discussion-between-v4n1ll4-and-jakehallas).

Comment: Upvoted for the part about $redirectedPath. That is all we need to do for the built-in 'auth' middleware.