# Laravel-5 redirecting to /home after login on click browser back

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have read this:
[Laravel-5 redirecting to /home after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793034/laravel-5-redirecting-to-home-after-login)

and in AuthController I have set

```
protected $redirectPath = '/user/info';
```

and after login it gets to this page. But when clicking browser back button - it does for some reason go to /home url.

Why is that? Previous page should be login page.

Comment: It cannot be the login page as you've already been authenticated..

Comment: OK, then why not to page which is specified in $redirectPath?

Comment: I have had a problem after login, look at this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-after-login if that helps let me know

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem in hacky way:

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    // fix after log in when user clicks back - it wants to redirect to not existing home page
    return redirect('/my-existing-page');
});
```

Comment: You should do this only if you're authenticated

Comment: If I will not be authenticated, then 'my-existing-page' will redirect to login page, because it is under middleware 'auth'

Comment: This hack is not good.. You should try and figure out why its not working properly and fix it. When you click back button is more like a browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default middleware [RedirectIfAuthenticated.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php)? If so, that is what is redirecting you - it checks if you are authenticated (which you are, since you just logged in) and redirects to **"/home"**. For whatever reason, the **"/home"** path is hardcoded there.